# How to find and replace a list of strings through out the spreadsheet with google script

Tags: replace, google-apps-script

Items I have:
A large list A of strings in column A (unsorted)

```
name1 pattern1 pattern4
name5 pattern2
name4 pattern4
name2 pattern3 pattern1
name4 pattern4
```

A large list B of different string patterns that I want to remove from string in column A (include punctuation and special characters)

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
```

Once I compare each pattern in B with the string in A, it should output:

```
name1 pattern4
name5
name4 pattern4
name2
name4 pattern4
```

Now I have 2 difficulties.  I have a very simple test code, assuming there is only 1 pattern in list, the program executed error free however nothing happens in my google spreadsheet, which I can't explain why

```
function removeS(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
    var data = range.getValues();
    for(i in data){
        data[i].toString().replace(pattern,"");
    }
}
```

Also secondly are there anyways I can accomplish my task without doing nested loop? (One loop through everything in column A and another loop for list of patterns) It seems so inefficient as I am dealing with large data.  In Excel macro you can do sth like:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
.Replace pattern1, ""
.Replace pattern2, ""
```

and takes care of the need of using nested loops, although it takes manual work to add the patterns.

Comment: that's an interesting question and well presented... thx & +1. You mentioned that your patterns could include punctuation and special characters but are these patterns fixed or are they variables that the script should identify and handle automatically ? As you probably know, replace method is not the most "tolerating" tool ;-)

Comment: `pattern` is undefined

Comment: At this point I am assuming all these patterns are fixed, which can be just manually passed as strings like ".com", "a&b", etc. I might try regex to simplify once I get the whole structure down, which I don't know if that will complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option.  Although I'm not sure a more eloquent way than nested loops, without converting the returned spreadsheet values from a 2d to a 1d array.

I set a constant for the last row of the patterns column, assuming it was the short of the two columns (see comments in code for rational).

```
function cleanMe(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
    var data = range.getValues();

// get the array of patterns (all ranges returned as 2d array)
// because .getLastRow() or .getDataRange returns the last row in the spreadsheet with data
// not the last row of the range with data
// hardcoded the last row in column be so as not to 
// have to use conditions to check if values exist in range
    var patternLastRow = 3;
    var patterns = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + patternLastRow).getValues();

// 2d array to replace data in row A using range.setValues(newRange)
    var newRange = []; 

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    // use encodeURIComponent to contend with special charactes that would need escaping
     var newValue =  encodeURIComponent(data[i][0].toString());
      for(var p = 0; p < patterns.length; p++){
        var pattern = encodeURIComponent(patterns[p][0]);
        var index = newValue.indexOf(pattern);
        if(index >=0){
         newValue = newValue.replace(pattern,'');
         }
      }
      newRange.push([decodeURIComponent(newValue)]);
    }

    range.setValues(newRange);
}
```